Using variable from __init__.py in main does not work
I want to use a dictionary created in the init.py file:
import requests

request = requests.get('http://cloudconfig:8001/msprueba/desarrollo')

request.raise_for_status()

all_config = request.json()

property_sources = all_config['propertySources']

config = {}

for sources in property_sources:
    for key, value in sources['source'].items():
        if key not in config:
            config[key] = value

In my main.py I try to access config dictionary:
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from company.controladores import controladorRouter
from company import config


print(config['eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone'])


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await eureka_client.init_async(
        eureka_server="http://eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/",
        app_name="msprueba",
        instance_port=8000,
        instance_host="localhost"
    )
    yield
    await eureka_client.stop_async()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.include_router(controladorRouter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = uvicorn.Config("company.main:app", host="localhost", port=0)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    server.run()

when I run the code I get the error 'module' object is not subscriptable, if I create another variable and pass the config value to the new variable like this:
import requests

request = requests.get('http://cloudconfig:8001/msprueba/desarrollo')

request.raise_for_status()

all_config = request.json()

property_sources = all_config['propertySources']

config = {}

for sources in property_sources:
    for key, value in sources['source'].items():
        if key not in config:
            config[key] = value

global_config = config

And in my main.py file I use the new variable:
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from coompany.controladores import controladorRouter
from company import global_config


print(global_config['eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone'])


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await eureka_client.init_async(
        eureka_server="http://eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/",
        app_name="msprueba",
        instance_port=8000,
        instance_host="localhost"
    )
    yield
    await eureka_client.stop_async()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.include_router(controladorRouter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = uvicorn.Config("company.main:app", host="localhost", port=0)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    server.run()

Everything works fine, but I don't understand why, can someone explain me this please?
Note: init.py and main.py are in the same location

You overwrite the name config  in your if __name__ clause.

You are overwriting the same variable on your __name__
You can use another main function to avoid overwriting
def main():
   config = uvicorn.Config("company.main:app", host="localhost", port=0)
   server = uvicorn.Server(config)
   server.run()



if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()


What a fool!, you are right, thanks
